# Which is best to use Validation server side or client side

Tags: jsp, validation, client-side, server-side

AS in few days we planning for starting up with our web-based appplication, Can anybody state me which is the best of them as we will giving the same in various form's and login page.

Answer (score 1):

**What is validation?**

Validation is a process of testing and ensuring that the user has entered required and properly formatted information through the web form.

**What is Client-side validation?**

In client-side validation method, all the input validations and error recovery process is carried out on the client side i.e on the user’s browser. It can be done using JavaScript, AJAX, HTML5 etc.

**What is Server-side validation?**

In server-side validation, all the input validations and error recovery process is carried out on the server side. It can be done using programming languages like C#.NET, VB.NET etc.

**Differences and comparison:**

Client-side validation is faster than server-side because, the validation takes place on client side (on browser) and the networking time from client to server is saved.

On the other hand, server-side validation is done on the web server. Then the server renders the data into html page and sends back to the client (browser).

Server-side validation is more secure than the client-side as the user cannot see the code even he does a view-source.

**Client Side**

You want to validate input on the client side first because you can give better feedback to the average user. For example, if they enter an invalid email address and move to the next field, you can show an error message immediately. That way the user can correct every field before they submit the form.

If you only validate on the server, they have to submit the form, get an error message, and try to hunt down the problem.

(This pain can be eased by making "sticky" forms where the server remembers what was entered in each field and fills it back in, but client-side validation is still faster.)

**Server Side**

You want to validate on the server side because you can protect against the malicious user, who can easily bypass your JavaScript and submit dangerous input to the server.

It is very dangerous to trust your UI. Not only can they abuse your UI, but they may not be using your UI at all, or even a browser. What if the user manually edits the URL, or runs their own Javascript, or tweaks their HTTP requests with another tool? What if they send custom HTTP requests from curl, for example?

Not allowing for that is not only naive from a security standpoint, but also non-standard: a client should be allowed to send HTTP by whatever means they wish, and you should respond correctly. That includes validation.

Server side validation is also important for compatibility - not all users will have JavaScript enabled.

**Conclusion:**

Both the validation methods have their own significance. I would like to recommend that you should use both the validation methods Client-side validation to provide a better user experience and server-side to be sure that the input you get from client (browser) is actually validated and not just supposed to be validated by the client.